# Правила словообразования в русском языке

Tags: словообразование

Уже многократно обсуждался тот факт, что русский язык - это вынос мозга для иностранца. А уж словообразование в русском языке - и подавно. Например, почему у таких похожих слов "стол" и "стул" совершенно разные формы множественного числа: "столы", то "стулья"? Или почему одно - яйцо, два - яйцА, пять - яиц, а много - Яйца? Или почему опять же похожие слова "река" и "рука" не склоняются с одинаковым ударением: "рЕками", но "рукАми"?
Это я все к тому, чтобы спросить у знающих людей, а есть ли в русском языке вообще какие-то правила словообразования? И, если есть, откуда в них столько исключений?

Comment: "РукАми", скорее всего, сохранило ударение от устаревшей формы "рукАма".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо,всё упирается в историю языка и происхождение слов. Стол -общеславянское, склоняется, как все русские слова с   -ол и чередованием е/о (стелить-стол;).

Др.- р. столя - крыша и стеля - потолок; столъ- скамья, от него уменьшит. стольць - мягкая основа.

Стул-заимствовано из германских языков в 16 веке, там та же основа, но с перегласовкой о в у -несколько другая основа, потому и склонение во множ. числе другое.(как кол-колья)

Правила словообразования есть, а исключения надо искать в истории, в исторической основе слова.